# (VB.net) detect if a key has been pressed?

Tags: vb.net, events, keyboard

i am making a program that checks to see if the C key was pressed and then executes a code

```
 Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Do
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.C Then
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To 4
                My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{SPACE}")
            Next
        End If
    Loop
```

i have tried using this code here but i get an unhandled exception error whenever i start the program

Can somebody please help?

Comment: You wrote this in button click event, what exactly you want???
You want like when C is pressed, button1 also pressed???

Comment: You written in Button_Click event which is actually EventArgs parameter and you even changed to keyEventArgs. This will show unable to cast problems in program, better option, write it in Button1.KeyDown , it will be easy to handle your key events and will perform specific task I guess... Inform me whether it worked.. @GamblerUS

Comment: Do you want the key event happen even if your program has no focus?

Comment: i want to be able to click the button, and after it is clicked if you press c it will execute the code, i have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 2):

1. Set first the KeyPreview = True of your Form.
2. Add KeyDown Event to your form and add your condition statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys(" ", True)
```